# Can WaitForSingleEvent wait for a event to be reset ?

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, events

I am trying to write a thread body (say, `myThread`) which is synchronized with the parent thread using a manual reset event,  say `g_myThreadEvent`.

This Event is used by `myThread` to notify the parent that it has successfully retrieved the input parameters.

I was wondering whether the same event can be reused by the parent to signal `myThread` to exit.

Some thing in the below lines  :

CHILD:

```
g_myThreadEvent = UNSIGNALLED.
myThread() {
    read_inparam()
    set(g_myThreadEvent);
    for(;;) {
       // do something important
       if(is_reset(g_myThreadEvent)) break;
    }
}
```

PARENT:

```
start_thread(){
    CreateThread(myThread, some_arguments);
    WaitForSingleobject(g_myThreadEvent, INFINITE);
}

stop_thread() {
    reset(g_myThreadEvent);
}
```

This would enable me to use a single event for synchronizing the threads, instead of the easier solution of using a separate event for stopping the thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Events don't have an "is-reset" state. They do, however ,have an is-set state (and the contra-positive to that, *is-not-set*). Clarity not withstanding (it would be *much* clearer to use a separate event), your child-thread could simply break when the event is no longer signaled:

```
// in child-infinite-loop. break if event no longer signaled
if (WaitForSingleObject(g_myThreadEvent, 0) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
    break;
```

and the parent thread can control this by resetting the event when the child is to terminate. A proper startup would be something like:

```
// startup the child thread
g_myThreadEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
g_hChildThread = CreateThread(....);
WaitForSingleObject(g_myThreadEvent, INFINITE);
```

and a proper shutdown would be:

```
// signal a shutdown to the running child.
ResetEvent(g_myThreadEvent);
WaitForSingleObject(g_hChildThread, INFINITE);
CloseHandle(g_hChildThread);
```

It is important your parent should ensure the child is *finished* by both resetting the event *and* waiting for a proper shutdown signal on the child thread handle. Shutdown race-conditions are born from not heeding this closely.

Finally, note this will only work for **one** child thread per event handle, a most-inconvenient restriction if it doesn't suit your specific needs.

Best of luck.

Comment: What happens if I set g_myThreadEvent from the child thread and immediately reset it before entering the processing loop ?  I'm  assuming the parent should get notified as the g_myThreadEvent was set. (then i should be able to wait for g_myThreadEvent to be set from my child thread)

Comment: @s_b The activity your describing is what [`PulseEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684914(v=vs.85).aspx) is designed to do. It releases *active* waiters. However, there is no such guarantee the parent is actively waiting at the time the child initiates the pulse. It has a natural race condition. The parent could start the child thread, which runs past the pulse (no parent waiting yet), then the child falls into the loop checking for the event as signaled, then the parent finally runs, waiting for the same event signal, but now there is no one to signal it.